# Compare only time from datetime in entity framework 6 with odp.net Oracle 12c

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, odp.net

I am using entity framework 6 with oracle and Sql. Timespan datatype is not working with oracle. so i changed datatype to datetime. now i want to compare only time in datetime with Linq query. ex.

```
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.GetAll().Where(e => e.ExecutionTime.TimeOfDay == viewmodel.ExecutionTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

in above example e.ExecutionTime is datetime  and viewmodel.ExecutionTime is timespan. i am using timeofday function to convert it to timespan

above query failed to execute so i used DbFunctions.CreateTime() function

```
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.FindBy(e => DbFunctions.CreateTime(e.ExecutionTime.Hour, e.ExecutionTime.Minute, e.ExecutionTime.Second) == exetime).FirstOrDefault();
```

above ex exetime is timespan.still i am getting below error

```
{"Invalid parameter binding\r\nParameter name: ParameterName"}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run the first code?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822588/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timespan-in-entity-framework-query?rq=1. Check that answer as it is better than converting things to strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the date- and time-problems with oracle, we do it string-only:

```
using(MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    TimeSpan myTime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
    string myTimeString = myTime.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss");
    List<ExecutionObjects> tmp = ctx.ExecutionObjects.Where(a => a.ExecutionTime.EndsWith(myTimeString)).ToList();

    // Access field in source with seperated DateTime-property.
    tmp.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.ExecutionTimeDateTime.ToShortDateString()));
}
```

In the source you can add an DateTime-parsing-property:

```
public class ExecutionObject
{
    [Column("ColExecutionTime")]
    public string ExecutionTime { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime ExecutionTimeDateTime {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(this.ExecutionTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            this.ExecutionTime = value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

Not the most beautiful version, but working.

This is an Oracle-based problem in the DbFunctions. If you activate the sql-log you'll see that a function "CREATETIME()" is used, which is unknown.

Activate sql-log:
ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

The log will look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "ExecutionTimes" "Extent1"
 WHERE ((((CREATETIME (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (CAST (
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare only the time you can use the supported EDM canonical functions from DbFunctions (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/Mapping-LINQ-Canonical-Functions-Oracle-Functions.htm#ODPNT8081)).
Unfortunately DbFunction.CreateTime is not supported.

Still, if you are interested in a comparison for example at the level of seconds, you can do something like this:

```
        var refTime = new DateTime(2017, 12, 13, 09, 30, 31);
        using (this.ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            var results = this.ctx.Groupings.Where(e => DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(e.EndDate, refTime) % 86400 == 0).ToList();
        }
```

Here you take the difference in seconds using the EDM function DiffSeconds and make the modulus with the number of seconds in a day.

The query that gets executed is:

```
select
  "Extent1"."GROUP_TYPE" as "GROUP_TYPE",
  "Extent1"."GROUP_ENTITY_ID" as "GROUP_ENTITY_ID",
  "Extent1"."ITEM_ENTITY_ID" AS "ITEM_ENTITY_ID",
  "Extent1"."DATE_START" as "DATE_START",
  "Extent1"."DATE_END" AS "DATE_END"
from "MYSCHEMA"."ENTITY_GROUP_REL" "Extent1" where (0 = (mod( extract( day from ( cast(:p__linq__0 as timestamp(9)) -  cast("Extent1"."DATE_END" as timestamp(9))))*24*60*60 +  extract( hour from( cast(:p__linq__0 as timestamp(9)) -  cast("Extent1"."DATE_END" as timestamp(9))))*60*60 +  extract( minute from ( cast(:p__linq__0 as timestamp(9)) -  cast("Extent1"."DATE_END" as timestamp(9))))*60 +  extract( second from ( cast(:p__linq__0 as timestamp(9)) -  cast("Extent1"."DATE_END" as timestamp(9)))) ,86400)))
```

As you can see it translates correctly to the oracle functions server-side.

I hope it helps,

Nicola

Answer (score 1):

EF6 query translator does not support `DateTime.TimeOfDay`, and Oracle provider does not support `DbFunctions.CreateTime` and `TimeSpan` parameters/constants.

Still there are some options before switching the storage from `DateTime` to `string` as suggested by another answer.

First, for equality checks you could compare the time components by either extracting them into separate variables (query parameters):

```
var hour = viewmodel.ExecutionTime.Hours;
var minute = viewmodel.ExecutionTime.Minutes;
var second = viewmodel.ExecutionTime.Seconds;

var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.FindBy(e => 
    e.ExecutionTime.Hour == hour && e.ExecutionTime.Minute == minute && e.ExecutionTime.Second == second)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

or into fake `DateTime` variable (queryParameter):

```
var executionTime = DateTime.Today + viewmodel.ExecutionTime;
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.FindBy(e => 
    e.ExecutionTime.Hour == executionTime.Hour && e.ExecutionTime.Minute == executionTime.Minute && e.ExecutionTime.Second == executionTime.Second)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Second, you can work with time converted to seconds. This allows you also to perform any comparison:

```
var executionTime = (int)viewmodel.ExecutionTime.TotalSeconds;
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.FindBy(e => 
    60 * 60 * e.ExecutionTime.Hour + 60 * e.ExecutionTime.Minute + e.ExecutionTime.Second == executionTime)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But doing all that manually is quite annoying and error prone. What I can offer is s small utility class providing custom extension method:

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ConvertTimeSpans<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var expr = new TimeSpanConverter().Visit(source.Expression);
        return source == expr ? source : source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expr);
    }

    class TimeSpanConverter : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        static readonly Expression<Func<DateTime, int>> ConvertTimeOfDay = dt =>
            60 * (60 * dt.Hour + dt.Minute) + dt.Second;

        static int ConvertTimespan(TimeSpan ts) => 
            60 * (60 * ts.Hours + ts.Minutes) + ts.Seconds;

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Type == typeof(TimeSpan))
            {
                if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(DateTime) && node.Member.Name == nameof(DateTime.TimeOfDay))
                    return ConvertTimeOfDay.ReplaceParameter(0, base.Visit(node.Expression));
                // Evaluate the TimeSpan value, convert and wrap it into closure (to keep non const semantics) 
                return ConvertTimespan(base.VisitMember(node).Evaluate<TimeSpan>()).ToClosure().Body;
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Left.Type == typeof(TimeSpan))
                return Expression.MakeBinary(node.NodeType, Visit(node.Left), Visit(node.Right));
            return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }
    }

    static T Evaluate<T>(this Expression source) => Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(source).Compile().Invoke();

    static Expression<Func<T>> ToClosure<T>(this T value) => () => value;

    static Expression ReplaceParameter(this LambdaExpression source, int index, Expression target) =>
        new ParameterReplacer { Source = source.Parameters[index], Target = target }.Visit(source.Body);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => node == Source ? Target : node;
    }
}
```

It uses two small custom `ExpressionVisitor` classes to convert the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property and `TimeSpan` class properties similar to your `viewModel.ExecutionTime`.

Now you should be use your original query like this:

```
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.GetAll()
   .Where(e => e.ExecutionTime.TimeOfDay == viewmodel.ExecutionTime)
   .ConvertTimeStamps() // the magic happens here
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

In case you want to use milliseconds instead of seconds, all you need is to change the first two statements in `TimeSpanConverter` class as follows:

```
static readonly Expression<Func<DateTime, int>> ConvertTimeOfDay = dt =>
    1000 * (60 * (60 * dt.Hour + dt.Minute) + dt.Second) + dt.Millisecond;

static int ConvertTimespan(TimeSpan ts) => 
    1000 * (60 * (60 * ts.Hours + ts.Minutes) + ts.Seconds) + ts.Milliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert both oracle timespan and SQL datatime in string and then compare it. Like:

```
var db0010016 = _idb0010016Rep.GetAll().Where(e => e.ExecutionTime.TimeOfDay.ToString() == viewmodel.ExecutionTime.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: You could use Equals to compare the strings